# How to get root Password in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux

The last time when I used Kali Linux, I was logging with the root user. Now it has been changed, I log in with a normal user. I don't know the root password. How will I get a root password

Comment: Have you tried `sudo su` after you log in as a normal user?

Comment: sudo su is used for switch to root user, I want to know the root user password.

Comment: You can't "know" another password; the system doesn't work that way. Just run *sudo passwd root* and change it.

Comment: @VijayKumar.  You cannot easily recover the root password.   Just run `sudo su` to become root.  Then run `passwd` to change the root password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run a command with root privileges in Kali Linux preface that command with `sudo` and authenticate by entering your user password. Your user password in Kali Linux is the same as the password that you use to login to your normal user account with.

If that doesn't work and you have forgotten your user password, then you need to reset your lost administrative password. You need to authenticate with your administrative password in order to [add your normal Kali Linux user to the `sudo` group as a `sudo` user](https://askubuntu.com/q/70442/).

---

#### Reset lost administrative password

1. Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

   The timing when to press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key can be tricky, so sometimes if you miss it you need to try it again. If that doesn't work try the answers to [I can't get the GRUB menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/87409/).

   You will see a GNU GRUB menu screen that looks like this. Select **Advanced options for Kali GNU/Linux** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image]
2. A new blue screen will appear showing a list of kernels, which includes options of booting the kernels normally or in recovery mode.

   [image]

   Press the down arrow key until you select the **2nd entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode in the description**) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.
3. Now you should see this recovery menu. From the Recovery Menu screen, use the arrow keys scroll down to ***root**  Drop to root shell prompt* and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image]
4. You'll see a root prompt, something like this: `root@kali:~#`. Remount it with write permissions:

   ```
    mount -rw -o remount /
   ```
5. To reset the password, type `passwd username` where you replace `username` with the username you use to login with.
6. You'll be prompted to type a new password. When you type the password you will get no visual response acknowledging your typing to prevent other people from seeing your password as you type it. Type your new password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. You'll be prompted to type your new password again as a check to make sure that you have typed it correctly. Type your new password again and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
8. You will see a message that says: `passwd: password updated successfully` showing that your password has been successfully reset. If Kali Linux is installed on an SSD, type `sync` to force changed blocks to disk and update the super block.
9. Type `exit` to return to the recovery menu.
10. From the Recovery Menu select `resume Resume normal boot` to resume booting normally.

Comment: Thank you for sharing information